# Error:Failed to resolve app.support v7-23.0.3 in android

Tags: android

A problem occurred configuring project app could not resolve all the dependicies for configurations app:debug could not find com.app.support v7-23.0.3

My gradle bundle file is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.quiz.activity"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support'

}
```

[image]

Comment: Wait for it to complete and show a tick mark against all of 23.

Comment: Well, `com.app.support v7-23.0.3` isn't a known dependency and neither is `'com.android.support'`... What does the actual message say?